# Need help identifying this font

Tags: font-identification, typefaces

I need help identifying this font. I have checked on WhatTheFont, WhatFontIs and Matchelator.

I get hits that are close but no matches.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: FOnt I need help with identifying]

Comment: ''Topographic Sans JNL'' did you check this font?

Comment: It is definitely not that one, no.

Comment: This is one of the fonts that's inspired by the U.S highway sign fonts -- the original version is called FHWA or sometimes 'Highway Gothic'.   Freely available versions include "Overpass Gothic", and paid versions include "Interstate".   The original signage version doesn't have an ampersand character (&).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is ***Expressway***.

Found the font here:
https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator

Comment: Thank you for down voting.

Comment: Who down voted this? Expressway is the closest match yet, yes.